# Extending Bootstrap Utility class in SCSS file

Tags: webpack, bootstrap-4, webpack-3

I am trying to use some of the utility classes from bootstrap in my scss file.

example

```
.pageTitle { @extend .p-3, border-bottom: 1px solid red}
```

I am importing bootstrap like this `@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-grid.scss';`

When I try to extend the utility classes in many files, I have to include bootstrap.scss in multiple which is increasing my bundle size when I try to bundle using webpack. It also increases my build time drastically.

Is there a way to include the `bootstrap.scss` once and bundle it once as well?

Answer (score -1):

You could have a main *scss* file where you first import the required bootstrap *scss* files than you include your library files too.

Let’s call this “master” file *project.scss* now. So, your *project.scss* file could look like this:

```
// Extended Bootstrap files
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-grid.scss';

// Projects styles
@import "typography";
@import "my-other-styles";
// …etc…
```

Where the *_typography.scss* and *_my-other-styles.scss* files are in the same directory as the *project.scss* file. This way all of your files will have access to the things that are defined in the imported Bootstrap files.

You could also have a look at the *bootstrap.scss* as an example. It first imports the functions, variables and mixins as these are used in the other *scss* files later on.